# TimeZone Name to Approximate Lat/Lng?

Tags: javascript, react-native, geolocation, timezone

I want to take a timezone name (`America/Los_Angeles`) and return the lat/lng (`{lat: 34.052235, lng: -118.243683}`) of the city it represents.

I'm trying to provide a better default map centering for users who may not want location services enabled on their phone by using their phone's timezone as a rough lat/lng lookup.

This feels like it should just be a lookup table that already exists and I could store in a data file, but all I'm seeing on Google and StackOverflow are lat/lng to timezone conversions. I *don't* want to need a service. Is there not a database or data file already out there with this information?

Comment: It sounds like you may be looking for the zone.tab file... see https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/zone.tab

Comment: Sorry, zone1970.tab is what you should use these days: https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/zone1970.tab

Comment: True, but I think for this particular function, `zone.tab` would offer slightly more precise values.  That said, not all time zones names are in there.  Especially not the `Etc/*` zones.  As a fallback, one could do a rough calc for the longitude based on offset - but latitude would still be ambiguous.